# Is there a way to keep the elements of the header on their "responsive position"?

Tags: css, header, html-email, responsive, mailchimp

I'm trying to design a header for an email newsletter that will be sent on Mailchimp. I've managed to make it the way I want it to be on the mail editor, however, when testing on other readers, the header goes completely bollocks. I believe the problem is on the positioning of elements, is that so?

I have tried several CSS positions combinations without any major success.

```css
.header {
 background-color: #5724a9 !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 14em;
    min-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}


.VER {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.logo {
  width: 28%;
  max-height: 12em;
  object-fit: contain;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-left: 14.5em;
  padding-right: 14.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" style="text-decoration: none;"> <p class="VER">Ver este email no browser</p></a>



<a href="https://www.instagram.com/desembola/" style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/38baf9eb-8971-4232-8877-e821fb206396.png" srcset="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/929291fe-8e66-433a-893d-860c863dd597.png 2x,
             https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/0668c4e9-df06-42cd-a8fb-0125371d2478.png 3x" class="instagram"></a>
             
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/desembolanews/" style="text-decoration: none;display: inline-block"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/d29b31ac-a288-47a3-aa9c-d2ab0b650374.png" srcset="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/e92c4f99-3f9a-4676-af77-0fa93f54c0e6.png 2x,
             https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/abb16351-fc77-4bf5-b34c-efa005ee76fe.png 3x" class="facebook"></a>            
     
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/5hmqdqrhlk9vcweti5ukuf3ow?si=dzJKoTzKSoGK_fuLByzZZQ" style="text-decoration: none;display: inline-block"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/7ab88f02-314e-4cc7-bbeb-0d3d216d1dac.png" srcset="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/433683ea-5f9d-4d3a-ac8c-ab0d4a6de392.png  2x, https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/e9d7c117-efdb-448c-aa7a-bdbe0a3ad2f5.png 3x" class="spotify"></a>
```

Expected: [image: https://imgur.com/prS310S]

Reality (on different browsers):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately e-mails are rendered in a very primitive way. Using `div`s and separate style declarations will most probably not work in most e-mail clients.

For starters you will **have** to use table layouts. Some best practices [here](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/)

And you will have to inline all your CSS, mailchimp tool: [here](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)

It's not worth your time trying to develop HTML emails like you would develop a website.
Once you make a start on the above, it should be easier for you to define specific problems with development.

Comment: Inliners are good but if you have code that's not read by email clients, it will be inlined which then bloats the code. I would suggest adding the CSS guide as well so (web devs) when doing emails, they dont over use codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done. Basically 3 columns with images and links in different columns.

You have to remember, emails are not web pages. Each element should have its own CSS inlined. Media query and global CSS can be in the head of the document but not all CSS will be read by all email clients. Check out the best [CSS guide created by Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) sometime ago. Its the best resource to start with when it comes to CSS.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="purple">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="200"><a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" style="text-decoration: none;color:#ffffff;"> <p class="VER">Ver este email no browser</p></a></td>
      <td align="center" style="color:#ffffff;">Logo here</td>
      <td width="100">
        
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/desembola/" style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/38baf9eb-8971-4232-8877-e821fb206396.png" srcset="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/929291fe-8e66-433a-893d-860c863dd597.png 2x,
             https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/0668c4e9-df06-42cd-a8fb-0125371d2478.png 3x" class="instagram"></a>
             
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/desembolanews/" style="text-decoration: none;display: inline-block"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/d29b31ac-a288-47a3-aa9c-d2ab0b650374.png" srcset="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/e92c4f99-3f9a-4676-af77-0fa93f54c0e6.png 2x,
             https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/abb16351-fc77-4bf5-b34c-efa005ee76fe.png 3x" class="facebook"></a>            
     
<a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/5hmqdqrhlk9vcweti5ukuf3ow?si=dzJKoTzKSoGK_fuLByzZZQ" style="text-decoration: none;display: inline-block"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/7ab88f02-314e-4cc7-bbeb-0d3d216d1dac.png" srcset="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/433683ea-5f9d-4d3a-ac8c-ab0d4a6de392.png  2x, https://gallery.mailchimp.com/82a2f49caf501fc10ae6ea563/images/e9d7c117-efdb-448c-aa7a-bdbe0a3ad2f5.png 3x" class="spotify"></a>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```